# Text Align Center Not Working In IE

Tags: html, css

I have a panel, I am centering the body of the panel. It works great in all browsers except for IE... Can anyone tell me why?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

**CSS**

```
 .chart-center {
        text-align: -moz-center; /*firefox*/
        text-align: -webkit-center; /*safari, chrome*/
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-lg-4">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title text-center"><i class="fa fa-usd fa-fw"></i> My Chart</h3>
         </div>
          <div class="panel-body text-center chart-center">
              <div id="myID"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why these vendor values? Wouldn't `text-align: center` suffice?

Comment: Also, `margin: 0 auto` will center an element with defined dimensions, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Actually, the `text-center` bootstrap class should do the same as `text-align`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the default one:

```
.chart-center {
    text-align: center; /*default*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Actually, for this property, the vendor prefix is unecessary.

Comment: Well, then there's something you didn't inform us. It works http://www.bootply.com/sxYDYo0BwG

Answer (score 0):

`margin 0 auto` will work if the external div is larger than the internal one which is not the case here.

This works too:

```
.chart-center {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:100px;
    }
```